# headless exception in java using play framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am using joptionpane in java i got an error "play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.awt.HeadlessException" I put by code below and i am using play framework

```
enter code here
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Login into Your Account");

error message
         ! @6j9l3c30p - Internal server error, for (POST) [/login] ->
```

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[HeadlessException: null]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException: null
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:535) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:385) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:174) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at controllers.Application.login(Application.java:68) ~[na:na]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused. It looks like you trying to delivery a swing UI over http.

To build a UI with play you should consider using their scala templates and rendering html. You may want to walk through one of their tutorials to help you get started.

https://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-spring-data-jpa